# Go app won't compile in Ubuntu SDK

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, golang

I'm trying to create a new Ubuntu Touch App with Go and QML using the template in the SDK. The application won't build and gives the following error.

```
17:41:47: Running command go get -d -u gopkg.in/qml.v0
package gopkg.in/qml.v0/tref: C source files not allowed when not using  cgo or SWIG: tref.c
17:41:49: The process /usr/bin/go exited with errors.
Error while building/deploying project vsteamservices (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Run Go install"
17:41:49: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

Am I just missing something completely obvious? Has anyone actually gotten this working that can help me get this? I don't know enough about Go/QML to know how to debug/fix this and google searches don't actually give anything useful. But I would guess that the template should run out of the box. So I'm guessing I'm just missing something.